# apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 django

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache2, mod-wsgi

Previously my code was working with apache2, django and libapache2-mod-wsgi. But I had to use python3, hence I removed libapache2-mod-wsgi and installed libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3. Now I am getting an error when I restart apache2.

Below is the error from command  `systemctl status apache2.service`. I don't know why WSGIScriptAlias is not working for libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3.

```
The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Did you re-enable the Apache module for mod_wsgi after you installed the alternate version? IOW, run ``a2enmod wsgi``.

Comment: ya i did.. same ..getting this in ipaddress. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.   The error goes when i reinstall libapache2-mod-wsgi and restart apache2. But i want it to run on python3.

Comment: And have you check the Apache error log for the latest error. What you show above isn't what you would get for what you now say is error in browser.